# What level of interactibility does the Summon natural allies spell grant over summons that can speak?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I play a Gnome Alchemist with the Preservationist archetype. In my formulae I have Summon nature's allies (I, II, IV and so on...), which allows me to summon creatures to help me do things (fight, and other things). Usually I summon (fire) elementals.

What are the limitations of the interactions between them and me / them and the group ?
Can I give them simple orders such as "attack this thing"? At what cost?
Can I give them complex orders such as "Go look over that wall and then come back to tell me what you saw"?
Would either of those require a roll for Handle Animal?
Would either of those require communicating with the summoned creature in a non-innate way (for example learning Ignate language)?

For example when I summon a fire elemental to "burn that house" what actions are required from me after the actual summon?

- Speak "Burn the house" in common to the Elemental?
- Speak "Burn the house" in ignate, the fire elemental's language?
- Gesture towards the house?
- Concentrate and wish it really hard until it works?

I feel I have a huge need to learn Ignate eventually but I'd like to know how far can I go without it.

Comment: Hey!  I think this question already has an answer on the linked question (the Q says Summon Monster but the answers take SNA into account as well).

Comment: @DavidReeve Sorry, I'm playing with french version of the names so maybe my translations aren't spot on. The spell is the one from the "Collector"'s archetype (maybe another translation error from me?), automatically added to your formula list at given levels. I don't think the marked-as-dup answer really answers my question as I feel it's outrageously unbalanced and renders the spell almost useless in combat. A full round to tell your last-round-summoned 10hp creature to attack the thing next to it? meh

Comment: Dealing with summoned elementals (and other creatures possessing language) is different from dealing with summoned creatures having Intelligence scores of 1 or 2. If you wanted to revise your question to focus on creatures with language *only*, that *might* be specific enough to reopen the question.

Comment: If y'all need to discuss please take it to chat.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Edited and specified :)

Comment: This is still answered by the other question. Not liking those answers isn't really a factor - consensus is yeah, you need to speak their language or it's hard to control them.